# Use Client Side USB port from Citrix/Terminal Server

Tags: terminal-server, citrix

Is it possible to use a scanner connected to the client PC via a USB port via Citrix or Terminal Server?

If it is can you provide a pointer to some information on how to set it up. We are using TWAIN to talk to the scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citrix and TS do not support scanner redirection out of the box.

There are a number of 3rd party utilities that will do this.  Another option is to use a "network USB" type device to connect the scanner into the Citrix session.

http://www.remote-scan.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about Quest's vWorkspace product:

http://www.vworkspace.com/solutions/vWorkspace/enterprise.aspx

Brian Madden was raving about it recently - a must read for all Citrix heads. Can't vouch for it as haven't tried it myself but we have a similar requirement and this caught my eye:

*Enhanced End-User Experience and Last-Mile Features: Coupled with Quest’s Experience Optimized Protocol, vWorkspace offers desktop and application publishing, seamless windows, up to 4096X2048 screen resolutions, multi-monitor support, single sign-on, smartcard authentication, USB redirection, user profile management, and a universal print driver, ensuring an optimized PC-like user experience.*

That's USB redirection is the specific bit.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scanner, the types of features you're looking for, client (9.x+) and XenApp (4.0) versions, you may be able to utilize the out-of-the-box TWAIN redirection feature of Citrix XenApp.

More info available here:
http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX107409